# Sort Products on QuoteLineItems

Tags: partner-wsdl, quotelineitem, sort

I am using Salesforce API 27 in .net tool to sync quote and opportunity from external system. However quote in external system and salesforce has not the same order. Salesforce is performing sorting on the Product Name field.

I have tried to use of SortOrder field on quote line items object but it says : 'Unable to create/update fields: SortOrder. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.'

PLease suggest or I am good with any workaround in API Code.